# jQuery UI Sortable set manually a position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

How can I manually set a position with some code?

Ok

Ive got some div with the sortable() behavour :

```
<div class="sort" id="a"></div>
<div class="sort" id="b"></div>
<div class="sort" id="c"></div>
<div class="sort" id="d"></div>
<div class="sort" id="e"></div>
```

I want to set manually(click on a button) the order with sortable jquery ui behavor with some code
To get something like this

```
<div class="sort" id="b"></div>
<div class="sort" id="c"></div>
<div class="sort" id="e"></div>
<div class="sort" id="d"></div>
<div class="sort" id="a"></div>
```

Any idea

Comment: since your are new here, there are some rules on how you post a question. You will need to post the code you have. If you can't post your code, you can make up some sample code, and try to reproduce your issue. You can always use jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: manually how? on page load or by clicking a button?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't a built-in option to reorder the elements, however using jQuery you can reorder the elements like this:

```
$("#sortable").sortable().disableSelection();
$("#sortable li:eq(3)").insertAfter($("#sortable li:eq(4)"));
$("#sortable li:eq(0)").insertAfter($("#sortable li:eq(4)"));
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fqAKu/)**. Original order: A, B, C, D, E. New order: B, C, E, D, A.

Comment: Ok i've though about that but how can i make a function for X elements to sort ?

Comment: You want to turn this into a function, or you need a function to handle a different series? Are you specifying the series?

Comment: i need a function to handle a different series ex : from 0 to 10 or for 0 to 13

Comment: How would you specify the order you want it sorted?