# Converting String Seperated by Comma and Hash to Array

Tags: javascript, string, arraylist, local-storage, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jquery sortable() to create draggable and sortable boxes.

The JQuery code looks like this:

```
    $('.column').sortable({
    connectWith:                '.column',
    handle:                     '.header',
    cursor:                     'move',
    placeholder:                'placeholder',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    opacity: 0.8,
    stop: function(event, ui)
        {
            $(ui.item).find('h2').click();
            var sortorder='';

            $('.column').each(function(){
                var itemorder=$(this).sortable('toArray');
                var columnId=$(this).attr('id');
                sortorder+=columnId+'='+itemorder.toString()+'&';
            });
            sortorder = sortorder.substring(0, sortorder.length - 1)
            console.log('SortOrder: '+sortorder);
            //localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(sortorder).sortable);
            localStorage.setItem("sortables", sortorder);
            //localStorage.getItem("sortables");
        }
    }).disableSelection();
```

The string it produces after the sort order turns out like this which is then saved into the local storage:

"col1=box3,box2,box1&col2=box4"

I am having a hard time trying to convert it back to the array and I also wanted to know once it is converted back to an array how do I take this array and apply it back to the sort order of the boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have stored and retrieved the sort order from localStorage, you want to run through each of your columns, "appending" the portlets to them in the same order in which they were previously in the columns.  As such, the last portlet will be appended last, and the first portlet first.

Here is the code:

```
    var str = localStorage.getItem("sortables." + window.location.pathname);
    if (str) {
        var cols = str.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
            var col = cols[i].split('=');
            if (col[1].length > 0) {
                var vals = col[1].split(',');
                for (var j = 0; j < vals.length; ++j) {
                    console.log('appending ' + vals[j] + ' to ' + col[0]);
                    $('#'+col[0]).append($('#'+vals[j]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/bWXZU/10/

Please note that there are several conditions you want to handle correctly:  (and the code above does)

1. When nothing is in local storage
2. When a column has no items

Hope this helps you out!

john...

Comment: Thank you so much John! I couldn't have done this without your help! Its guys like you why I still have my job :) 

Forever thankful! 
Sunny

Comment: Hi John, I have another quick question. I just realized when there are multiple pages with this code and different box id's from pages to pages. The code will only grab the last localstorage. I was wondering if there was a way to combine previous saved local storage with any new ones being created?

Comment: My approach to this dilemma would be to have page specific IDs for your localStorage items.  That is, instead of calling all of them "sortables", I would have: page1.sortables, page2.sortables, page3.sortables.  Each page would then have it's own ID, and have a separate storage location for it's portlet order.  To get a page specific ID, you can either have each page specify their ID separately, or perhaps take a look at window.location.pathname (if each page is always referenced from its own URL pathname).  I would lean toward each page supplying it's own ID.

Comment: Thank you again John! - what I have done was replace the var "sortables" with location.pathname. Its now working :)

Answer (score 1):

Try a simple iterate like below to create an `object` with key as `col1` and value as an array `[box3, box2, box1]`

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/2yt5y/2

```
var str = 'col1=box3,box2,box1&col2=box4';

var cols = str.split('&');
var result = {};
for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
   var col = cols[i].split('=');
   var vals = col[1].split(',');

   result[col[0]] = vals;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that Vega. I got it to work with your code snippet. But how do I take this result and apply it back to the sort order? I am extreamly newbe at this

Comment: @user1467439 Check this one out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981563/jquery-ui-sortable-set-manually-a-position.. I am doing something else at this moment.. Will look at this later today.

Comment: I am currently looking at it, still trying to figure it out. The example is only showing how to sort one list, I am not sure how to translate this for the two column divs. Its starting to look very complicated.